# Can't scroll to an element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to visit next page after searching. I'm getting the first page, but in order to go to next page i need to scroll down to click next page element.I've tried different methods as shown in the code to scroll down the webpage but despite all attempt i'm still getting ElementNotVisibleException  error. Can anyone tell me why the scrolling isn't working.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get('https://www.texasbar.com/am/Template.cfm;jsessionid=7EB4486736A022DC2AB99C24E9071D70.cfusion?Section=Find_A_Lawyer&template=/Customsource/MemberDirectory/Search_form_client_main.cfm&CFID=39868973&CFTOKEN=2f314a81f05a55c6-469AE4D3-91FD-AA7B-9D59C8F7DB39779F')
time.sleep(4)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("Zip").send_keys("75001"+"\n")
time.sleep(6)
new = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[name=\"HiddenFormFields\"] > a.next-btn.btn")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 7664)")
#driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
#driver.send_keys(Keys.END)
new.click()
time.sleep(4)
pagesource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: Try taking a full page screenshot and see if that really is the case? Or allow selenium to open a browser that you can watch firefox/chrome? Phantomjs might not be doing what you expect.

Comment: @jmunsch I have taken screenshot. It seems the next page icon is present in the screenshot of phantomjs. The screenshot link is http://i.imgur.com/m7RlphL.png  But the look of next link icon is different in browser and phantomjs screenshot. Still since the next link is present in the screenshot it probably should work, but it isn't working

Answer (score 2):

Finally i have solved the problem. Before getting the url, i have set the browser window size `driver.set_window_size(1124,850)` and it's solved.